# javascript - adding multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have several arrays of arrays... e.g.

```
var a = [[45, "question1", "answer1"], [22, "question2", "answer2"]];
var b = [[55, "question3", "answer3"], [12, "question4", "answer4"]];
```

Each array is coming in from a different page

I then wanted to push them together to get

```
var c = [[45, "question1", "answer1"], [22, "question2", "answer2"], [55, "question3", "answer3"], [12, "question4", "answer4"]];
```

I did this by

```
var c = a;

c.push(b);
```

When I tried to sort this, it comes out all wrong which tells me that the push has done something like

```
var c = [[45, "question1", "answer1"], [22, "question2", "answer2"]], [[55, "question3", "answer3"], [12, "question4", "answer4"]];
```

Can someone help, or point me towards the answer? I need to be able to sort on the first element of the array across all of the joined array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `.concat()`, not `.push()`.

Try:

```
var c = a.concat(b);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats cracked it!  I think I have been sitting in front of this screen for too long....